# Starting Lubuntu in VirtualBox shows a messy UI sometimes

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Lubuntu VM running in VirtualBox on Windows 10. Sometimes when I start it, the screen is a total mess like this:

[image]

When this happens (which WAY too often), I have to power off the machine and start it again and again until it shows up normally. What is the cause and how do I get rid of it?

When I created the VM, I think I just went with mostly default settings, but essentialy they are:

- 8192MB RAM
- 1 CPU
- 64MB Video memory
- 1 Monitor
- No 3D or 2D acceleration enabled
- Graphics controller: VBoxVGA (VBoxSVGA has the same results)
- Guest additions have been installed and updated
- I have updated VirtualBox many times and am currently using the latest version 6.0.14

Comment: Did you try updating the HOST Video Driver, and probably BIOS as well.

Comment: I did update the video driver for my GTX 1060 just now which did not help, and I already have the latest BIOS version for my motherboard. Maybe the issue is somehow related to LXDE desktop environment?

Comment: (a) Perhaps get a trial of VMware Workstation and see if Ubuntu works properly that way. I have Ubuntu (not Lbuntu) working fine that way. (b) Try Ubuntu in Virtual Box and see if that works.

Comment: I think the LXDE was the culprit. I did full system upgrade and updated the underlying Ubuntu to 19.10 (I was using 18.04 before) and LXDE got also replaced with LXQt. Now it seems to work fine, I did multiple restarts and screen did not get messed up at all.

Comment: Did my answer above help you?

Comment: I did not try VMware or plain Ubuntu. I installed Manjaro KDE in VirtualBox and it worked fine, I think Ubuntu would have worked too. For this reason I think there was some compatibility issue with my GPU and LXDE running in VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed by upgrading the distribution using `sudo do-release-update`. I upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10, and LXDE also got replaced with LXQt. My guess is that there was some sort of weird compatibility error related to LXDE.